# Partial Differential Equation $U_t - (U_x)^2 = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Please can anyone help me solving this problem?

$$ \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} - \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\right)^2 = 0 $$

where $U=U(x,t)$ with side condition as $U(x,0)=\cos x$.

The problem is given in the following article: A. Thess, D. Spirn, B. Jüttner, "Viscous Flow at Infinite Marangoni Number", *Physical Review Letters* 75(25), 1995. [doi:10.1103/PhysRevLett.75.4614](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.75.4614)

Comment: Shouldn't Burgers' equation have $\partial^2 U/\partial x^2$ rather than $(\partial U/\partial x)^2$ ?

Comment: it's special case in it

Comment: the problem is given in the physical review letters volume 75, Number 25 Viscous flow at infinite Marangoni Number.

Comment: You've asked the same question twice now.

Comment: This question got migrated from physics to mathematics, so it appeared twice in mathematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article cited in OP deals with the convection problem $\partial_t \theta + v \partial_x \theta = 0$, where $v = -H\theta$ is expressed in terms of the Hilbert transform $H\theta$ of $\theta$. While discussing this model, the authors make some statements on the alternative model (p. 4615, top of 2nd column)

> $v = -\partial_x\theta$, which leads to the well-known Burgers equation $\partial_t\theta - (\partial_x\theta)^2 = 0$

This is actually an Hamilton-Jacobi equation, which classical resolution relies on the Lax-Hopf formula.
A Burgers-like equation is recovered after differentiation of the above PDE with respect to $x$:
$$
g_t - 2 g g_x = 0, \qquad\text{with}\qquad g = \theta_x .
$$
The solutions deduced from the method of characteristics satisfy the implicit equation  $g = -\sin (x +2g t)$ of which no analytical solution is known. This classical solution is valid up to the breaking time $t=1/2$ when it breaks down, as displayed on the plot of the characteristics in $x$-$t$ plane below:

[image: characteristics]

Along the characteristic lines, the variable $g = -\sin(x_0)$ is constant. Moreover, we have
$$
\frac{\text d}{\text d t} \theta = \theta_x \frac{\text d}{\text d t} x + \theta_t = -2g\theta_x + \theta_t = -g^2 ,
$$
so that $\theta = \cos(x_0) - g^2  t$ along the characteristics. Thus,
$$
\theta = \cos(x +2g t) - g^2  t, \qquad\text{with}\qquad
g = -\sin(x +2g t) .
$$
Below is a Matlab script for this computation, along with its output (requires Optimization Toolbox):

```
nx = 200;
nt = 10;
tf = 0.49;
x = linspace(0,2*pi,nx);
t = linspace(0,tf,nt);
g = -sin(x);
theta = cos(x);

figure(1);
clf;
subplot(1,2,1);
hg = plot(x,g,'k-');
xlim([0 2*pi]);
ylim([-1 1]);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('g');
ht1 = title(strcat('t =',num2str(t(1))));
subplot(1,2,2);
htheta = plot(x(2:nx),theta(1,2:nx),'k-');
xlim([0 2*pi]);
ylim([-1 1]);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('\theta');
ht2 = title(strcat('t =',num2str(t(1))));

for i = 2:nt
    fun = @(g) g + sin(x+2*g*t(i));
    g = fsolve(fun,-((x<pi).*x+(x>pi).*(x-2*pi))/(1+2*t(i)));
    theta = cos(x+2*g*t(i)) - g.^2*t(i);
    set(hg,'YData',g);
    set(htheta,'YData',theta(2:nx));
    set(ht1,'String',strcat('t =',num2str(t(i))));
    set(ht2,'String',strcat('t =',num2str(t(i))));
    drawnow;
end
```

[image: output]

Comment: I too proceeded in the same way and got the same result g= -sin(x+2gt) but can't we solve further to get thetha?

Comment: In Matlab, I am facing this problem with the above code "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." and thus unable to obtain the second plot. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

This equation can be solved by the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). Let us start by changing variables, and use the field

$$v(x,t) = -2 \partial_x U(x,t) \, .$$

Indeed, in terms of $v(x,t)$, the problem is

$$ \partial_t v + v \partial_x v= 0 \, , \qquad v(x,0) = f(x) = 2 \sin(x) \, . \qquad (*)$$

Then the solution of this differential equation comes from the observation that

$$ \frac{d}{dt}v(z(t),t) = 0 \, , \qquad \text{if} \qquad \frac{dz}{dt} = v(z(t),t) = v_0 = f(z(0)) \, .$$

The right-hand-side of the second equation is a constant as a consequence of the first equation that tells us that $v(z(t),t)$ is a constant. Then if in order to compute $v(x,t)$, we need to find $x_0$ such that $z(0) = x_0$ and $z(t) = x$. I.e. solve

$$ f(x_0) t + x_0 = x \, , \qquad \rightarrow \qquad x_0 = x_0(x,t) \, . \qquad (**)$$

In the case $f(x) = 2 \sin(x)$, this has to be done numerically for most choices of $x$ and $t$. Finally this solution can be inserted back into

$$v(x,t) = v(z(t),t) = v(z(0),0) = v(x_0(x,t),0) = f(x_0(x,t)) \, .$$

Modulo the numerical solution of ($**$), this answers the question.

Things get difficult (and interesting) when ($**$) can not be solved. With $f(x) = 2 \sin(x)$, this happens when $t\geq 1/2$ and ($**$) has multiple solutions. Then ($*$) can not be solved. It is however possible to circumvent this problem by coming up with a prescription to decide which solution to pick. With such a prescription, it turns out that that $v(x,t)$ jumps from one solution to another as $x$ is changed. $v(x,t)$ develops discontinuities for $t>1/2$ and displays so-called shocks. See e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation).

An intuitive (and physically based) prescription is to introduce a viscosity term

$$ \partial_t v + v \partial_x v=  \nu \partial_x^2 v \, , \qquad (***)$$

and define the solution of ($*$) as the solution of ($***$) in the limit $\nu \rightarrow 0$. As long as $\nu >0$, ($***$) has a smooth and well defined solution. This solution becomes however discontinuous in the desired limit $\nu \rightarrow 0$, and shocks emerge naturally. Moreover, in the absence of shocks, the limit $\nu \rightarrow 0$ can be taken straightforwardly and the solutions of limit of the solution of ($*$) coincides with the solution of ($***$).

I conclude with a short comment on terminology: To me (and also to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation)), ($*$) is Burgers' equation and $\partial_t U - [\partial_x U]^2=0$ is the [KPZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardar%E2%80%93Parisi%E2%80%93Zhang_equation) equation without viscosity and noise. These two names are often mixed up because both equations are equivalent as I show in the beginning of my answer.

I quickly wrote a short Mathematica code to solve the above equation up to $t=1/2$:

```
X0[x_, t_] := x0 /. FindRoot[2 Sin[x0] t + x0 == x, {x0, x}]
v[x_, t_] := 2 Sin[X0[x, t]]
U[x_, t_, Npts_] := -1/2 Sum[v[x (i - 1)/(Npts - 1), t] x/(Npts - 1), {i, 1, Npts}] + 1
```

The first line solves ($**$), the second line computes $v(x,t)$ and the third line converts it back to $U(x,t)$ with the correct initial conditions. I implemented the integration over $v(x,t)$ as a Rieman sum with $Npts$ the number of discrete elements. With $Npts=50$, I get the following plot:
[image]

The vertical axis represents $U$, the horizontal axis (from $2\pi$ to $0$) is $x$ and the 'depth' axis (from $0$ to $1/2$) is $t$. The plot is generated in Mathematica with

```
Plot3D[U[x, t, 50], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 1/2}]
```

The formation of a shock at $x=\pi$ and $t=1/2$ is visible here as a kink in $U(x,t)$. Remember that $v = -2 \partial_x U$, so that a kink in $U$ is equivalent to a jump in $v$.

Comment: Can we simply use variable saperation method to solve this?

Comment: No. If you try the ansatz $U(x,t) = X(x) T(t)$, you quickly find that the obtained equations are not compatible with the initial conditions $U(x,0) = cos(x)$. I guess that (and would be happy if someone else can confirm) separation of variables does not work because the equations is non-linear. With a linear equation, you can use linear combinations of solutions to construct the desired initial conditions (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Applicability)).